# TypeScript: How to define custom typings for installed npm package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript1.8

I like to use [rx-node](http://npmjs.com/package/rx-node) within TypeScript

```
import RxNode from 'rx-node';
```

I installed [rx-node](http://npmjs.com/package/rx-node) using npm

```
$ npm install rx-node --save
```

I searched for type definitions, but without any result

```
$ typings search rx-node
No results found for search
```

How can I define custom type definitions for the installed npm module [rx-node](http://npmjs.com/package/rx-node)? Where should I store the type definition file? How to configure TypeScript (*tsconfig.json* and *typings.json*)?

**Edit:** Thanks to [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642950/1065654) and [David Bohunek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642510/1065654) I achieved to define a `rx-node.d.ts` that looks like this

```
declare module "rx-node" {
  import {Observable} from '@reactivex/rxjs';
  import {ReadLine} from "readline";

  function fromReadLineStream(stream: ReadLine): Observable<string>
}
```

I installed [@reactivex/rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#all-module-types-cjses6amdtypescript-via-npm)

```
npm install --save @reactivex/rxjs
```

Since I got an error

```
node_modules\@reactivex\rxjs\dist\cjs\Observable.d.ts (10,66): Cannot find name 'Promise'. (2304)
```

I changed the target in *tsconfig.json* to `es6`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Beware, this is old question (2016) regarding managing definitions using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) which is deprecated in favor of installing them straight via [npm](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-0/#simplified-declaration-file-dts-acquisition)

---

You can add custom definitions to *typings.json*. For example having following folder structure:

```
/typings
    /custom
        rx-node.d.ts
    /global
        ...
```

where rx-node.d.ts is your custom typings file. For example:

```
declare module RxNode {
    export interface ...
}
```

Then install with a command

```
typings install file:typings/custom/rx-node.d.ts --save --global
```

---

Or manually: in *typings.json* add reference to this typings file:

```
{
    "name": "TestName",
    "version": false,
    "globalDependencies": {
        "rx-node": "file:typings/custom/rx-node.d.ts"
    }
}
```

And run `typings install`

Comment: Running `typings install` copies `typings/custom/rx-node.d.ts` to `typings/globals/rx-node/index.d.ts`. If I change the type definition, I have to run `typings install` again to copy the changes. What is the advantage of this approach over referencing `rx-node.d.ts` manually in `index.d.ts`?

Comment: Personally I prefer to not edit auto generated files (and add ignore rule in source control). Also once typings defined they'll not change until original library is changed. And once "official" version available this can be easily replaced.

Comment: I assume this approach has now changed as of TypeScript 2.x, as the `typings` folder is redundant and all typings are installed via npm in node_modules/@types/...?

Is there a recommended approach for custom typings for missing definitions?

Comment: @Squiggle, yes and no. You can still use _typings_ with TS 2. If you choose to move to _@types_ -  custom local typings can be included with `"typeRoots"` compiler option (in case you'd like to store them separately from the other sources)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file, called it `rx-node.d.ts` and make sure it's referenced in your `tsconfig.json` either directly or from another file, for example `typings/index.d.ts`.
Then you can start with something like this:

```
///<reference path="rx.d.ts" />

declare namespace RxNode  {

    export interface Emitter<T>{

    }

    export function toEventEmitter<T>(observable: Rx.Observable<T>, eventName: string): Emitter<T>;
}
```

This question/answer might be helpuful: [How to write d.ts file from existing .js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137684/how-to-write-d-ts-file-from-existing-js-file/25138584#25138584)

If you create a nice, high quality typings definition file, contribute to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Great, there is already a [pull request](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/pull/17) :D

Answer (score 0):

For ReactJS projects using create-react-app (react-scripts), you can add a module declaration in `src/react-app-env.d.ts` for your untyped package.

```
declare module "not-typed";
```

Note: in future the location of this file may change, see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6560).