# TypeScript 2: custom typings for untyped npm module

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

After trying suggestions posted in [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641960/typescript-how-to-define-custom-typings-for-installed-npm-package), I find myself unable to get a typescript project running that uses an untyped NPM module. Below is a minimal example and the steps that I tried.

For this minimal example, we will pretend that `lodash` does not have existing type definitions. As such, we will ignore the package `@types/lodash` and try to manually add its typings file `lodash.d.ts` to our project.

Folder structure

- node_modules

  - lodash
- src

  - foo.ts
- typings

  - custom

    - lodash.d.ts
  - global
  - index.d.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- typings.json

Next, the files.

File `foo.ts`

```
///<reference path="../typings/custom/lodash.d.ts" />
import * as lodash from 'lodash';

console.log('Weeee');
```

File `lodash.d.ts` is copied directly from the original `@types/lodash` package.

File `index.d.ts`

```
/// <reference path="custom/lodash.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/lodash/index.d.ts" />
```

File `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "typings": "./typings/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

File `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots" : ["./typings"],
    "types": ["lodash"]
  },
  "include": [
    "typings/**/*",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

File `typings.json`

```
{
    "name": "TestName",
    "version": false,
    "globalDependencies": {
        "lodash": "file:typings/custom/lodash.d.ts"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried many different ways of importing typings:

1. By directly importing it in `foo.ts`
2. By a `typings` property in `package.json`
3. By using `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` with a file `typings/index.d.ts`
4. By using an explicit `types` in `tsconfig.json`
5. By including the `types` directory in `tsconfig.json`
6. By making a custom `typings.json` file and running `typings install`

Yet, when I run Typescript:

```
E:\temp\ts>tsc
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'lodash'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Unfortunately these things are not currently very well documented, but even if you were able to get it working, let's go over your configuration so that you understand what each part is doing and how it relates to how typescript processes and loads typings.

First let's go over the error you are receiving:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'lodash'.
```

This error is actually not coming from your imports or references or your attempt to use lodash anywhere in your ts files. Rather it is coming from a misunderstanding of how to use the `typeRoots` and `types` properties, so let's go into a little more detail on those.

The thing about `typeRoots:[]` and `types:[]` properties is that they are **NOT** general-purpose ways to load arbitrary declaration (`*.d.ts`) files.

These two properties are directly related to the new TS 2.0 feature which allows packaging and loading typing declarations from **NPM packages**.

This is very important to understand, that these work only with folders in NPM format (i.e. a folder containing a *package.json* or *index.d.ts*).

The default for `typeRoots` is:

```
{
   "typeRoots" : ["node_modules/@types"]
}
```

By default this means that typescript will go into the `node_modules/@types` folder and try to load every sub-folder it finds there as a **npm package**.

It is important to understand that this will fail if a folder does not have an npm package-like structure.

This is what is happening in your case, and the source of your initial error.

You have switched typeRoot to be:

```
{
    "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
}
```

This means that typescript will now scan the `./typings` folder for **subfolders** and try to load each subfolder it finds as an npm module.

So let's pretend you just had `typeRoots` setup to point to `./typings` but did not yet have any `types:[]` property setup. You would likely see these errors:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'custom'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'global'.
```

This is because `tsc` is scanning your `./typings` folder and finding the sub-folders `custom` and `global`. It then is trying to interpret these as npm package-type typing, but there is no `index.d.ts` or `package.json` in these folders and so you get the error.

Now let's talk a bit about the `types: ['lodash']` property you are setting. What does this do? By default, typescript will load **all** sub-folders it finds within your `typeRoots`. If you specify a `types:` property it will only load those specific sub-folders.

In your case you are telling it to load the `./typings/lodash` folder but it doesn't exist. This is why you get:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'lodash'
```

So let's summarize what we've learned. Typescript 2.0 introduced `typeRoots` and `types` for loading declaration files packaged in *npm packages*. If you have custom typings or single loose `d.ts` files that are not contained withing a folder following npm package conventions, then these two new properties are not what you want to use. Typescript 2.0 does not really change how these would be consumed. You just have to include these files in your compilation context in one of the many standard ways:

1. Directly including it in a `.ts` file:
   `///<reference path="../typings/custom/lodash.d.ts" />`
2. Including `./typings/custom/lodash.d.ts` in your `files: []` property.
3. Including `./typings/index.d.ts` in your `files: []` property (which then recursively includes the other typings.
4. Adding `./typings/**` to your `includes:`

Hopefully, based on this discussion you'll be able to tell why the changes you mad to your `tsconfig.json` made things work again.

### EDIT:

One thing that I forgot to mention is that `typeRoots` and `types` property are really only useful for the **automatic** loading of global declarations.

For example if you

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

And you are using the default tsconfig, then that jquery types package will be loaded automatically and `$` will be available throughout all your scripts wihtout having to do any further `///<reference/>` or `import`

The `typeRoots:[]` property is meant to add additional locations from where type *packages* will be loaded frrom automatically.

The `types:[]` property's primary use-case is to disable the automatic loading behavior (by setting it to an empty array), and then only listing specific types you want to include globally.

The other way to load type packages from the various `typeRoots` is to use the new `///<reference types="jquery" />` directive. Notice the `types` instead of `path`. Again, this is only useful for global declaration files, typically ones that don't do `import/export`.

Now, here's one of the things that causes confusion with `typeRoots`. Remember, I said that `typeRoots` is about the global inclusion of modules. But `@types/folder` is also involved in standard module-resolution (regardless of your `typeRoots` setting).

Specifically, explicitly importing modules always bypasses all  `includes`, `excludes`, `files`, `typeRoots` and `types` options.  So when you do:

```js
import {MyType} from 'my-module';
```

All the above mentioned properties are completely ignored. The relevant properties during **module resolution** are `baseUrl`, `paths`, and `moduleResolution`.

Basically, when using `node` module resolution, it will start searching for a file name `my-module.ts`, `my-module.tsx`, `my-module.d.ts` starting at the folder pointed to by your `baseUrl` configuration.

If it doesn't find the file, then it will look for a folder named `my-module` and then search for a `package.json` with a `typings` property, if there is `package.json` or no `typings` property inside telling it which file to load it will then search for `index.ts/tsx/d.ts` within that folder.

If that's still not successful it will search for these same things in the `node_modules` folder starting at your `baseUrl/node_modules`.

In addition, if it doesn't find these, it will search `baseUrl/node_modules/@types` for all the same things.

If it still didn't find anything it will start going to the parent directory and search `node_modules` and `node_modules/@types` there. It will keep going up the directories until it reaches the root of your file system (even getting node-modules outside your project).

One thing I want to emphasize is that module resolution completely ignores any `typeRoots` you set. So if you configured `typeRoots: ["./my-types"]`, this will not get searched during explicit module resolution. It only serves as a folder where you can put global definition files you want to make available to the whole application without further need to import or reference.

Lastly, you can override the module behavior with path mappings (i.e. the `paths` property). So for example, I mentioned that any custom `typeRoots` is not consulted when trying to resolve a module. But if you liked you can make this behavior happen as so:

```
"paths" :{
     "*": ["my-custom-types/*", "*"]
 }
```

What this does is for all imports that match the left-hand side, try  modifying the import as in the right side before trying to include it (the `*` on the right hand side represents your initial import string. For example if you import:

```js
import {MyType} from 'my-types';
```

It would first try the import as if you had written:

```js
import {MyType} from 'my-custom-types/my-types'
```

And then if it didn't find it would try again wihtout the prefix (second item in the array is just `*` which means the initial import.

So this way you can add additional folders to search for custom declaration files or even custom `.ts` modules that you want to be able to `import`.

You can also create custom mappings for specific modules:

```
"paths" :{
   "*": ["my-types", "some/custom/folder/location/my-awesome-types-file"]
 }
```

This would let you do

```js
import {MyType} from 'my-types';
```

But then read those types from `some/custom/folder/location/my-awesome-types-file.d.ts`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. 
It turns out the solutions work in isolation, but they don't mix well.
It does clarify things so I'll give you the bounty. 

If you could find the time to answer a few more points, that might be really helpful for other people. 
(1) Is there a reason for typeRoots to only accept a specific folder structure? It seems arbitrary.
(2) If I change typeRoots, typescript still includes the @types folders in node_modules, contrary to the spec. (3) What is `paths` and how is it different from `include` for the purpose of typings?

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you, I read the rest and wow. Props to you for finding all of this. It looks like there is a lot of unnecessarily complex behavior at work here. I hope Typescript will make their config properties a bit more self-documenting in the future.

Comment: Apologies for barging in like that but @dtabuenc - could you have a look at my question too please? I have a similar problem but can't get it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42233987/1288418

Comment: There should be a link to this answer from http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Shouldn't the last example be like `"paths" :{
   "my-types": ["some/custom/folder/location/my-awesome-types-file"]
 }` ?

Comment: @dtabuenc: I tried with files: [], angular 6 starts the application but nothing displayed on page. it did not throw any error but page and console is blank.

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) is a handy link about path mapping

Comment: When I use the path-mapping `"*": ["my-custom-types/*", "*"]` I get **Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving** issues. See [angular-#15452](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15452#issuecomment-525285680). This solved it for me:: `"some-lib": ["some-lib", "path/to/my/custom-typings/some-lib"]`

Comment: @DanielTabuenca I have tried removing typeRoots and each of your standard ways, but none of them work. My question is related at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74626880/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-custom-declaration-file-in-typer

Answer (score 7):

Edit: out of date. Read the answer above.

I still don't understand this, but I found a solution.
Use the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./typings/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Remove `typings.json` and everything under folder `typings` except `lodash.d.ts`. Also remove all the `///...` references

Answer (score 4):

`"*": ["./types/*"]` This line in tsconfig paths fixed everything after 2 hours struggle.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./types/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": [
    "client/**/*",
    "packages/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

*types* is the folder name, which sits beside node_module i.e in the level of *client* folder (or *src* folder)
`types/third-party-lib/index.d.ts` 

*index.d.ts* has `declare module 'third-party-lib';`

**Note:** The above config is an incomplete config, just to give an idea of how it looks like with types, paths, include and exclude in it.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but typescript tooling has been continuously changing. I think the best option at this point is just rely on the "include" path settings in tsconfig.json.

```
  "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
```

By default, unless you make particular changes, all *.ts and all *.d.ts files under `src/` will be automatically included. I think this is the easiest/best way to include custom type declaration files without customizing `typeRoots` and `types`.

Reference:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html