# How to import modules with ‘Typings’ in TypeScript without <reference>?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, typescript-typings

I`m trying to write tests with **Protractor** and **Jasmine** in **TypeScript**. TSD is now deprecated so I have to use 'Typings' to manipulate TypeScript definitions. So I installed it:

```
npm install typings -g
```

Then I used it to install Jasmine and Chance definitions like that:

```
typings install jasmine --source dt --save –-global
typings install chance--source dt --save –-global
```

And I also added **“files”** section and excluded 'node_modules':

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "tmp",
    "types": ["node", "jasmine", "chance"]
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "lib",
    "specs"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The problem is neither WebStorm nor Visual Code studio can`t find definitions for all Jasmine methods and 'chance' module. Errors are:

```
**“TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'”** 
**“TS2307: Cannot find module 'chance'”**
```

respectively. Here is my spec file:

[image]

In 'typings/' folder I see reference links to TypeScript definitions:

[image: folders structure and typings/index.d.ts content]

Am I missing something? Why my IDE can`t find definitions for Jasmine and Chance?

**P.S.** Test works after transpiling to Javacript.

**P.S.S.** Errors will disappear after adding

```
///<reference path="###"/>
```

to the spec file. But I don`t want to use it.

```
Protractor: 4.0.9;
TypeScript 2.0.3;
Typings 1.5.0;
```

Thanks  in advance!

Answer (score 8):

There's a few things that are preventing things from working well for you. First of all, if you are using *Typescript 2.0* then `typings` is also sort of deprecated.

*Typescript 2.0* supports packaging typings in node modules (usually installed by `npm install @types/module-name`. All declarations available on definitely typed are also available as npm modules under the "@types/*" namespace, so if you are looking to move away from `tsd`, `typings` should not be your final destination.

That being said, typescript 2.0 will still work with typings so let me point a few of the issues I see in your config file.

### Types Property

```
{ 
    "types": ["node", "jasmine", "chance"]  
}
```

The types, property is meant to only be used with the new npm package-based typings in `@types/*`. Since you are not using this yet, you should not have this property in your `tsconfig.json`. (See [TypeScript 2: custom typings for untyped npm module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module/40326719#40326719) for a full discussion of what this and related properties do.

### Files/Include/exclude properties

```
{
 "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "lib",
    "specs"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

While you can chose to use both files and include properties at the same time, this is not necessary. You can move your `typings/index.d.ts` reference from the `files` array and into the `include array` and then just eliminate `files`.

Also, the big problem you have is that your `include` syntax is wrong. `include` takes **glob** patterns. You cannot just simply put folder names, but need to follow them by a recursive pattern:

```
{
  "include": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "lib/**/*",
    "specs/**/*"
  ],
}
```

The last thing is that you do not need to exclude `node_modules`. Exclude is only necessary to exclude things that would otherwise match your include patterns. Since `node_modules` would not be matched by your `include` patterns, there is no need to exclude it.

I think if you make these small changes things should work as you expect, but again, I would really look into going all the way and migrating to the new `@types/*` based typings, as they are much easier to manage and more convenient and do not require an external tool (other than npm) like typings or tsd.

Comment: There is a good example of a project setup for Protractor with TypeScript (https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-typescript). I also agree that you should use TypeScript 2.0...also there is a `@types/chance` published.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `compilerOptions` as follows:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "tmp",
    "typeRoots": ["./typings"] // Updated!
  },
```

`typeRoots` automatically includes all definition files under the specified folder(s) in your compilation without the need to add a references directive to the relevant files, or the need to create an index file (which you then need to update whenever you add a new ambient library).

Your current configuration (`"types": ["node", "jasmine", "chance"]`) will only search for definition files in `node_modules/@types`, and then only include the `node`, `jasmine`, and `chance` definitions.

This is explained in detail in the [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) documentation.

EDIT: You're using a JetBrains IDE. If the IDE is compiling the JS for you, make sure it's using your `tsconfig.json` for settings instead of its own. It's in the preferences.