# How to configure custom global interfaces (.d.ts files) for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I'm currently working on a ReactJS project which uses Webpack2 and TypeScript. Everything works perfectly apart from one thing - I can't a find a way to move interfaces that I've written myself into separate files so that they are visible to the whole application.

For prototyping purposes I initially had interfaces defined in files that use them but eventually I started adding some that were needed in multiple classes and that's when all the problems started. No matter what changes I make to my `tsconfig.json` and no matter where I put the files my IDE and Webpack both complain about not being able to find names (*"Could not find name 'IMyInterface'"*).

Here's my current `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "types": [
    "typePatches"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my `tsconfig.json` is in the root of the project directory, all source is in `./src`, I placed my custom `.d.ts` files in `./typings` and included it in `typeRoots`.

I tested it with TypeScript 2.1.6 and 2.2.0 and neither works.

One way of getting it all to work is to move my `typings` directory into `src` and then `import {IMyInterface} from 'typings/blah'` but that doesn't feel right to me as it's not something I need to use. I want those interfaces to just be 'magically' available throughout my application.

Here's a sample `app.d.ts` file:

```js
interface IAppStateProps {}
interface IAppDispatchProps {}
interface IAppProps extends IAppStateProps, IAppDispatchProps {}
```

Do I need to `export` them or maybe `declare`? I hope I don't have to wrap them in a namespace?!

### Update (October 2020)

Seeing how this question is still surprisingly popular I wanted to explain the solution in more detail.

Firstly, what could and should be confusing to people is that the interface example I gave at the end of my question actually doesn't have any `export` keywords even though I'm almost certain I did have them in my files at the time of asking the question. I believe I didn't include them in the question thinking they didn't make any difference, whether they were there or not. Well, it turns out that it's not true and the `export` keyword is exactly what makes or breaks you being able to just "use" the interfaces versus having to explicitly `import` them.

So, the way it works in TypeScript is as follows:

If you want an interface/type that you can simply use without having to import it in the consuming module said interface must reside in a `.ts` or ideally a `.d.ts` file **without any imports or exports being present in the same file**. This is of utmost importance because as soon as you are exporting at least one thing from the same file it becomes a module and everything that is in that module must be subsequently imported by consumers.

To give you an example let's assume you want to have a type called `Dictionary` that you want to be able to use without importing. The way to declare it would be as follows:

```js
// types.d.ts
interface Dictionary {}
interface Foo {}
interface Bar {}
```

To use it you simply do:

```js
// consumer.ts
const dict: Dictionary = {};
```

However, it will no longer work if for some reason **any** of the interfaces/types in that file are exported, e.g.:

```js
// types.d.ts
interface Dictionary {}
interface Foo {}
export interface Bar {}
```

It will also not work if there are imports in that file:

```js
// types.d.ts
import { OtherType } from 'other-library';

interface Dictionary {}
interface Foo extends OtherType {}
interface Bar {}
```

If that is the case the only way to be able to use the `Dictionary` type would be to also export it and then import it in the consumer:

```js
// types.d.ts
export interface Dictionary {}
interface Foo {}
export interface Bar {}

// consumer.ts
import { Dictionary } from './types';

const dict: Dictionary = {};
```

`--isolatedModules`

There is an additional quirk to keep in mind when using the `isolatedModules` modules flag in TypeScript, which, importantly, is enabled by default (and cannot be disabled) when using Create React App - `.ts` files MUST export at least one thing as otherwise you will be getting the *"All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided."* error. That means that putting the `Dictionary` interface in a `types.ts` files without the export keyword won't work. It must either be an export from a `.ts` file of be a declaration without the export in a `.d.ts` file:

```js
// types.d.ts
interface Dictionary {}        // works
export interface Dictionary {} // works

// types.ts
interface Dictionary {}        // doesn't work with --isolatedModules enabled
export interface Dictionary {} // works
```

N.B.
As @dtabuenc mentions in his answer ambient modules (`.d.ts` files) are discoraged and my correction shouldn't be taken as advice. It's just an attempt at explaining how normal modules and ambient modules work in TypeScript.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

"Magically available interfaces" or global types is highly discouraged and should mostly be left to legacy.  Also, you should not be using ambient declaration files (e.g. `d.ts` files) for code that you are writing. These are meant to stand-in the place of external non-typescript code (essentially filling in the typescript types into js code so that you can better integrate it with javascript).

For code you write you should be using plain `.ts` files to define your interfaces and types.

While global types are discouraged, the answer to your issue is that there are two types of `.ts` files in Typescript. These are called `scripts` and `modules`.

Anything in a `script` will be global. So if you define your interfaces in a script it will be available globally throughout your application (as long as the script is included in the compilation through either `///<reference path="">` tags or through `files:[]` or `includes:[]` or the default `**/*.ts` in your `tsconfig.json`.

The other file type is 'module', and anything in a `module` will be private to the module. If you export anything from a module it will be available to other modules if those other modules chose to import it.

What makes a `.ts` file a "script" or a "module"? Well.... if you use `import/export` anywhere in the file, that file becomes a "module". If there are no  `import/export` statements then it is a global script.

My guess is you have inadvertently used `import` or `export` in your declarations and made it into a module, which turned all your interfaces to private within that module. If you want them to be global then you would make sure you are not using import/export statements within your file.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! It turned out my issue was (as you suggested) that I was importing classes/interfaces from other files into my declaration files. As soon as I removed those imports and only left clean `interface Foo {}` declarations everything worked. 

As per globals - I completely see why having declarations to be magically available is a bad practice and am considering switching to a custom module (actually tried `declare module MyApp { export interface Foo {} }` and could successfully import it by doing `import { {Foo} from 'MyApp'`) but for now magic works for me :)

Comment: Holy shit man. I just wasted an entire day not knowing what I was doing. Thanks a lot. This answer needs to go to official doc if it's not there already.

Comment: I halted a project for a week, wondering why it wasn't working. I private learning stuff that would not have lasted three days otherwise. Tanks of thanks [dtabuenc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2625248/dtabuenc)

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I imported the `SyntheticEvent` interface from React to use in my own type definitions and everything stopped working. I should have caught that sooner, but here we are. Thanks!

Comment: @dtabuenc Can you support your statement that global types are deprecated?
Looking at the official documentation I can't get that impression.

Comment: Very clear explanation! This topic is opaque in typescript official doc and many beginners feel confused(myself included) about it. Thanks!

Comment: you must also know that in `tsconfig.json` the `isolatedModules` parameter should be false for this to work.

Comment: "Magically available interfaces" is one of the two ways to provide basic IDE support for JS-based DSLs, and the other way is **LITERALLY HUNDREDS IF NOT THOUSANDS OF TIMES HARDER**: write plugins for all IDEs.

Comment: This is literally the first paragraph I said: "They are meant to stand in for **EXTERNAL NON-TYPESCRIPT** code (feels so awesome to  use **BOLD**.  If you are writing **TYPESCRIPT** (which the original poster was, you should not be using global type declarations to export your own types, but rather use the typescript module system.

Comment: Also, even when using type definitions in IDEs for javascript, it is increasingly common (and preferred) for those definitions to be modular (particularly if the javascript library is itself modular), rather than globally available script-based d.ts files.

Comment: How can I make it require an import?  my Arrays.ts has a declare global { interface Arrays<T> {...  and several Array.prototype. .... declarations ?  Thank you

Comment: There's a big difference between "generally discouraged" and "should never do".  There are valid reasons to use globals, which is why the ability exists.

Answer (score 12):

The term is "global" interface, **not** "Magically available interface".

And in some `.d.ts` file, I extend global `Window` interface, like:

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface Window {
        // Below just informs IDE and/or TS-compiler (it's set in `.js` file).
        myGlobalVariable: any;
    }
}
```

Using the same technic, we could create custom-global-interfaces (instead of extending existing).

### Example

```
import React from 'react';

declare global {
    interface MyGlobalInterface {
        myComponentField: React.Component;
    }
}
```

> **Note** that because `.d.ts` files do not produce any output, we can import whatever module (as long as the module is installed by `package.json` of course).
>
> Also, above example does not need the `export {};` line,
> because it does have an `import`,
> I mean, the rule was to at least have one `import` or one `export` (at time of writting).
>
> Finally, the `.d.ts` file's name(s) and location(s) do **not** matter, but I prefer placing `globals.d.ts` file beside root js/ts file of project, just to be sure it's loaded first.

Comment: To add to this, if you want to declare global variables such as those injected by your bundler.. This is the place I like to put them. If the global.d.ts has imports, then just declare your consts within the `declare global` parenthesis same as above.

`declare global { declare const __PROD__: boolean; }`