# Why don't I need to export/import TypeScript Interfaces?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an Angular 5 application along with my coworker. I created a folder for all my interfaces and grouped them by feature. However, I did not include any export notation on them and, when using them, I never have to import them...they just exist and don't create any compile errors. I like it this way because it keeps the code cleaner but am I just taking advantage on some bug? My coworker did it the "right" way and needs to import anytime he wants to use an interface. Any ideas? How should you create interfaces that exist in separate files? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you have no import or export in your file, it's not a module, and what you define in it clutters the global namespace. If you ever need to import some type in one of these files, you're doomed. And if you ever have two different interfaces with the same name, you're doomed.

Comment: Interfaces exist only for the compiler to validate against; they don't exist at runtime. You do not need to export/import them. You can, of course, and it can make it easier to keep track of where the interface is.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Not really though since all interface code is removed at compile. It solely exists for the IDE. Not sure why I would be doomed to import files into one of these, I do it just fine. I did, at one point, have 2 interfaces named the same and it did cause a compile error but I am not sure that wouldn't happen anyway.

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript

Comment: Suppose you have a main.ts file using the interface Bar defined in bar.ts, without importing it since it's not exported. Now Bar needs an additional field of type Foo which is a class exported from foo.ts. So bar.ts now needs to import Foo from foo.ts, and becomes a module. And Bar is thus not visible globally anymore. So it now needs to be imported in main.ts and in every file using it. If you had exported it from the start, you would not have to add the missing import from all the files using Bar and assuming it's global.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an Angular 5 application I believe you are using angular_cli. I checked using interface without exporting, but, I did get an error on serving angular project in the terminal. Please check the terminal.

Comment: Sometimes....I get a compile error and the app still works. However, if I shut down the server and start it again (full re-compile?) all the errors go away.

Comment: yes, [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript) sums up why this works. As a good practice, I feel avoiding globals are better way as it might confuse other developers who will work on the project as they need to search for the interface.