# Usage of types and interface without importing

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I recently moved to typescript to write React Native applications and one thing I have noted is that I can use types without importing/exporting them. I have placed all the definition files under the `@types` folder.

Is it the correct way of doing it without exporting and importing types?

If I import an external type from `node_modules/` (say `ViewStyle` from `react-native`) and use it in my interface, it says "Cannot find the name" in VScode and I have to export the interface and import it where it's required to solve this.

I am trying to use the least possible amount of imports.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: You should import the types. They are dependencies of the file and should be explicitly listed as such. Global types should only be used for global variables

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure custom global interfaces (.d.ts files) for TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript)

Answer (score 8):

**First** option:

You can use [TS namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) - it will reduce the amount of imports in your app (you don't have to import each type from namespace manually). For example, let's say we have `app.namespace.ts` file:

```
export namespace AppConfig {
  export interface BaseConfig {
    url: string;
    port: number;
  }

  export type MyMap<T> = {
    [key: string]: T;
  }

  export class Settings {
    public p1: boolean;
    public p2: number;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { AppConfig } from './app.namespace';
// ...
baseConfig: AppConfig.BaseConfig;
myMap: AppConfig.MyMap<number>;
// ...
```

**Second** option:

Just create `.d.ts` files in your projects (usually each application sub module have its own models file, so you can create `some-feature.d.ts` inside your feature folder). In this case you can use any type from the d.ts files without importing.

Check this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yefjvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.d.ts)

Comment: What if I have a ton of interfaces and I don't want to have 20-30 interfacename.d.ts files hanging out in my main folder? I also don't want to put them all in the same file. How would you recommend handling this?