# Can't use interfaces from another file when they import any dependencies

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with interface import. When I have interface with non import dependencies in separate files like:

`/src/app/something/something.interface.ts`

```
interface ISomething {
    a: String[];
}
```

I can use it in another file in the same directory without import it, fo example:

`/src/app/someting/something.tsx`

```
class Something extends React.Component<ISomething, any> {

}
```

But when I have interface like this:

```
import Page from '../components/page';

interface ISomething {
    a: String[];
    b: Page;
}
```

I get an error from compilation process:
`[2] ERROR in src/app/something/something.tsx(9,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ISomething'.`

I try to use `export interface ISomething ...` and import them in `something.tsx` but this get an error

```
[2] ERROR in src/app/application/education/react/renderer/renderer.tsx(8,9): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/xxx/Projects/react/src/app/something/something.interface"' has no exported member 'ISomething'.
```

When I put my `ISomething` interface in `something.tsx` file it work, but I want to keep it clean in separate file.

Do you have any idea why?

EDIT:
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "preserveWhitespaces": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript.

Comment: I don't need global access, only import for specyfic file.

Comment: Apologies - that was hasty on calling it a duplicate. The question is different, but the underlying issue (difference between scripts and modules) is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to some odd default behavior in Typescript (mostly there for legacy purposes). By default, if you have a file with no import/export statements in it, and it's included in your tsconfig.json (by default, everything in tsconfig's directly is included), Typescript will treat it as a *script*, as opposed to a *module*, and make its identifiers available in global scope.

You can disable this behavior by changing the value of `module` in your `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json. Which value you want depends on where this code is going, but using `es6`, for example, should give you the desired behavior.

Comment: I try to change compiler options into 'es6' but I doesn't see any difference in compilation process. I got the same errors.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your tsconfig.json? That would be helpful in figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: I edit my question and paste `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`