# How to import `ts` modules in a `d.ts` file that uses `declare namespace`?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings, .d.ts

I decided to declare all the types that I'll need across my project into a single `d.ts` file.

**allTypes.d.ts**

```
declare namespace PROJECT {

  interface MY_INTERFACE {
    // ...
  }

}
```

And just by declaring that namespace, I'm already able to use in all my project files as:

```
const something: PROJECT.MY_INTERFACE = {
  // ...
};
```

[image]

And this has been working so far.

But now I need to declare a new type that is based on a existing JS object.

**@constants/COLLECTIONS.ts**

```
export const COLLECTIONS = {
  PROP_A: "PROP_A",
  PROP_B: "PROP_B",
  PROP_C: "PROP_C",
};
```

So I had to do the following in my `allTypes.d.ts` file.

**allTypes.d.ts**

```
import { COLLECTIONS } from "@constants/COLLECTIONS";

declare namespace PROJECT {

  interface MY_INTERFACE {
    // ...
  }

  type SOME_TYPE = keyof typeof COLLECTIONS   // THIS IS WORKING FINE

}
```

The problem is that just by doing that `import` on the top-level of my `allTypes.d.ts`, my `PROJECT` namespace is no longer visible for the files of my project.

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Wondering if you were ever able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I researched this a little more and this solution works in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114250/40769

Using import inline like the example below will still allow the use of script type *.ts/*.d.ts files.

```js
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: import("./user").User;
  }
}
```

This answer also had some useful context about the difference between a "script" and "module" ts file:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257742/40769