# How to include a non namepsaced module TS definition in my custom types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In my custom types I wish to make use of the `GraphQLSchema` from the `graphql` module. If I just write:

```
interface MyThing {
  schema: GraphQLSchema
}
```

It does not reference the `GraphQLSchema` definition from the module (it's just `any`). VSCode then suggests to auto add the import file:

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql'
```

The definition is now correct (i.e. hovering above it in VSCode pops the correct type) but now my custom type file no longer works - i.e. I cannot use `MyThing` in my code - it's no longer defined.

My tsconfig does include my custom typings as well as `node_modules/@types` - vscode seems to see it so I assume it's fine. I did try specifically adding the path to the graphql file containing the definition but no go.

I am able to use other definitions that are namespaced just fine without an import - just not that one.

Suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: They mention not using `import` in the definition files which is my problem but no answer that I can see on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - prob pretty obvious to experiences TS but wasn't to me. If there is an import statement then everything must be explicitly exported. I didn't have export statements in my file since TS didn't seem to care but I guess the moment you add an import then all must be exported.

Works (but no way to import)

```
interface MyThing {
  schema: any
}
```

Does not work

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql'
interface MyThing {
  schema: GraphQLSchema
}
```

Works with imports

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql'
export interface MyThing {
  schema: GraphQLSchema
}
```