# How to declare module in typescript `.d.ts`file?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I found this code in lodash's `.d.ts` file.

```
import _ = require("../index");
declare module "../index" {
    interface LoDashStatic {
     ...
    }
}
```

What dose this code declare? Why there is no `export` before `interface`?
What's the difference between with `export` or without `export` inside `declare module`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257742/96944