# Switching for dynamic keys breaks type definition

Tags: typescript

I had a type, defined as such in a definition file (`.d.ts`) (also, the code is shortened):

```
type myType = {
  [key: string]: any;
  myKeyOne: string;
  myKeyTwo: number;
};
```

which was working fine, but for the needs of my project, I need to make these keys a little bit more dynamic since they are prone to change a lot.

So I declared some constants in a `constants.ts` file:

```
export const MY_KEY_ONE = 'myKeyOne';
export const MY_KEY_TWO = 'myKeyTwo';
```

and used them as such in the previous file:

```
type myType = {
  [key: string]: any;
  [MY_KEY_ONE]: string;
  [MY_KEY_TWO]: number;
};
```

But it broke all my code, stating that it

> Cannot find name 'myType'

Am I not allowed to do that? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems to work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLIE0D6BpAUVwHkA5AuAXjgHIBbATz2AeOWBoG4AoUSWRCnRxs+IjgAqAdWJVajZgwkB3CF27cYDMMDiMJ23dQDe3OHADaAaxYAuOOigBLZAHMAuvYCGyBj3MWooQk5J4OMM5u-pZB4tLEYcgArnQARsBQPAC+PNxIaPAQ9vqGcqbmAbEhBGEARLUANGYVgbjBkjJhAAxNWUA

Comment: Ah, I was so tunnel-vision that I totally forgot to check on TS Playground... So it must be the project I'm on that's configured terribly. Does not come as a surprise either lol. Thanks!

Comment: Declare it 'as const' might helps : export const MY_KEY_ONE = 'myKeyOne' as const;

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER const declarations with literal initializers will automatically preserve the literal type without the need for `as const`

Comment: Why don't you export that type and import it where you need it?

Comment: I'm nowhere near a TypeScript pro, but I thought the whole point of having `.d.ts` files was to avoid importing/exporting types. Is it not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer here, for those who would encounter the same "unknown" problem.
[This S/O thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript), especially the **Update (October 2020)** part of the question, finally gave me the answer.

Basically, before making modifications, my definition file wasn't **importing/exporting** anything, making it a *script* and thus, making all definitions available globally. As soon as you import and/or export something, the *script* becomes a *module* and you **MUST** import/export anything you want to use in other files.