# How to ignore .d.ts file inside npm package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react-custom-scrollbars, the index.d.ts file inside package doesn't works for me, while @types/react-custom-scrollbars works well.

as this issue mentioned.
https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/issues/133

My problem is, before this package makes any change, can I use @types/react-custom-scrollbars instead of index.d.ts inside this package?

I try to add explicit reference path

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../node_modules/@types/react-custom-scrollbars/index.d.ts" />
```

In Visual Studio Code, it compiles. But when running, error still:

```
ERROR in /Users/alen/Workspace/Qunhe/core/node_modules/react-custom-scrollbars/index.d.ts
(3,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__React'.
```

Btw, I'm using webpack 2.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try excluding the bundled `index.d.ts` using `exclude` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. and I find an excellent answer about all this tings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module I got it works after set 'paths' of compilerOptions, I'll post my solution later.

Comment: I realized it's you again, last week you help me solved another question about typescript..

Comment: That's good. The problem you have is not a simple one. Glad that you found a solution.  The problem is that the TS team was reluctant on disabling the auto searching for typings inside the actual package. I know of an issue related to that. 

`path` is a nice way out of this by doing one-offs pointing the typings to somewhere else. I didn't think of using it for this purpose so nice find. :)

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```