# How to override or extend a libary type definition in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I import a library type declaration in Typescript. How can I extend the definition of that library when there's compiler issues with it, but it would be otherwise valid js code? For example validate.js type bindings are very inaccurate compared to the actual implementation. Something like shown below....

```
import * as validate from 'validate.js';

declare namespace validate {
  Promise: any;
  async: any;
}
```

Similarly with mongoose I can't access modelSchemas property but I need to.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
declare namespace mongoose {
  export modelSchemas any[];
}
```

So if I want to add definitions to the existing types just to shut the compiler up. How can I do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put additional typings in `custom-typings.d.ts` in root of `src`.

**custom-typings.d.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

//augment validate.js
declare module "validate.js" {
    let Promise: any;
    function async(param: any): any;
}

//augment mongoose
declare module "mongoose" {
    let modelSchemas: mongoose.Schema[]
}
```

**my-module.ts**

```
import validate = require("validate.js");
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird";

validate.Promise = Bluebird;
mongoose.Promise = Bluebird;

let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

mongoose.modelSchemas = [schema];

validate.async("foo");
```

[Why `import` with ES5 syntax (`require`)?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6751#issuecomment-245962235) ES6 modules and their properties are constant.

Comment: Thanks it's nearly working for validate.js but it's now giving error:  "Cannot assign to 'Promise' because it is a constant or a read-o
nly property" - but others have resolved. Also how to add a property to mongoose.Mongoose? I tried similar but couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. There is some extra juice - mongoose will use Bluebird as Promise library.

Comment: Ok thanks mongoose and validate.js errors have resolved now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't seem to get your answer to work with my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836379/extending-nextjs-default-types-with-typescript

Comment: Even more elaborate answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326719/1493423