# Typescript merge interfaces from multiple files

Tags: typescript

I have a file named `service.ts` which exposes the following code:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  keyOne: string;
}

export class TestService<T = SomeInterface> {
  property: T;
}
```

In `index.ts` file I am using the service:

```
import { TestService } from './service';

const service = new TestService();
service.property.keyOne
```

I also created `index.d.ts` file which declare the same interface `SomeInterface` with more keys:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  keyTwo: number;
}
```

The problem is that `service.property` only "knows" the `keyOne` property. How can I tell typescript to merge both of them?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cp8zmv

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (your comment in @chris p bacon's answer), you want to augment a module type definition from a library. The link to [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in TypeScript docs is already a good catch. There are some good answers out there dealing with third party lib type extensions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952198/how-to-override-or-extend-a-libary-type-definition-in-typescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690619/how-can-i-augment-a-property-within-a-third-party-typescript-interface-defined-a/48692419).

For your example, if we want to augment a library module type definition for some reason (let's say `vendor-lib.d.ts` instead of your `index.d.ts` to make it clearer), we can do that via [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

vendor-lib.d.ts:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  keyTwo: number
}
```

service.ts

```
// here for simplicity a relative import
import { SomeInterface } from "./vendor-lib"

// Augment above imported module. 
// Important: this file must be a module (not a script) via `import/export`.
// Then augmentation will work. Otherwise compiler expects a module declaration.
declare module "./vendor-lib" {
  interface SomeInterface {
    keyOne: string
  }
}
```

index.ts:

```
const service = new TestService(); service.property = {...};
service.property.keyOne // works
service.property.keyTwo // works
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tzzg8l)

Answer (score 3):

You'd extend the interface and give it another name

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  keyOne: string;
}

export interface SomeExtendingInterface extends SomeInterface {
  keyTwo: number;
}
```

Or merge them to a type that has both properties

```
interface Foo {
    foo: string;
}

interface Bar {
    bar: string;
}

type Baz = Foo & Bar;

const foo: Baz = {
    foo: '',
    bar: ''
};
```

Comment: It should work as I did according to the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: No matter if it works or not, why should two different interfaces ever have the same name? Don’t you think that’s confusing in a few months when maintaining your code? But do what you prefer...

Comment: The purpose is for users that use a library to be able to extend the interface globally.

Comment: @undefined Honestly, you should add that in your question as context, otherwise, it doesn't really make that much sense.