# Adding Types of 3rd Party Submodule

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components

How do I add types for a submodule of a node module? For example, say I install a module called `foo`, which has a submodule `bar`, which is imported like this:

```
import Bar from "foo/bar";
```

I tried the following, but it didn't appear to work (in `types/styled-components/primitives.d.ts`):

```
declare module "foo/bar" {
   // types
}
```

If it helps, the specific module I am trying to work with is `styled-components/primitives`, so if there are already types available somewhere I'm happy to pull those instead of defining them myself. `@types/styled-components` did not appear to include them.

Comment: Can you show some concrete code with `styled-components/primitives` you tried to get working?

Comment: @ford04 here is a gist of some code I included within `node_modules/@types/styled-components/primitives.d.ts` in the meantime. It basically just mirrored `styled-components/native`, so its not really correct but it was a temporary solution: https://gist.github.com/treyhakanson/2fd8c792e4811c00b995a39e4141faac

Comment: Sorry for posting late. Seems like styled-components does neither offer the type in its package, nor in @types. So you will have to define your own type module. As a start: Remove any import/export statement in `primitives.d.ts` and write `declare module "styled-components/primitives";` in it to type it as any. You may also have a look at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453347/typescript-merge-interfaces-from-multiple-files/57459260), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441879/bypass-implicitany-with-a-module-type/57443849#57443849)  (disclaimer: that are my answers).

Comment: Let me know, if that helps out.