# Override Express Request type in typescript. Error: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>.signedCookies: any

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types

I know there are already **a lot of topics** about this but I have tried 150 things and nothing works, the problem must come from my logic, but where ?

My custom express types file basically looks like this, I add two values that don't exist in Express Request, so far no problem, it works :

`./src/@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
import * as express from 'express';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      address?: Record<string,unknown>,
      file?: Express.Multer.File
    }
  }
}
```

---

**The problem is here**, I need to use `signedCookies` which is a property that already exists in Request by default under express, however it is set to `any` by default (which logically returns me an error, because I don't want `any` types).

`./src/controllers/usersController.ts`

```
'use strict';

import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export function getLogin(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const signedCookies = req.signedCookies;
}
```

Error on `req.signedCookies` :

> (property) Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>.signedCookies: any
> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment

---

So I tested *dozens of things* to replace the `signedCookies` type with something other than `any`, but nothing worked, including this.

`./src/@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      address?: Record<string,unknown>,
      file?: Express.Multer.File,
      signedCookies?: Record<string,unknown>
    }
}
```

I also tried to redefine the `express-serve-static-core` module with the values or extends the Request interface, but nothing works, the error is always the same.

I should add that **it works for `address` and `file`** (maybe because they are values that did not already exist?).

---

`./tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "test"],
}
```

If someone has a **solution**, a **topic** or *anything* to help me, I'm interested !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of TS, and as far as I can tell it's because you cannot override the keys of interfaces. IIRC this was a design decision intentionally made and probably has no way of changing in the foreseeable future.

For example:

```js
// imagine this definition is from the library
namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    signedCookies?: any
  }
}

namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    signedCookies?: Record<string, unknown>
    // ^ Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  
    // Property 'signedCookies' must be of type 'any', 
    // but here has type 'Record<string, unknown> | undefined'.
  }
}
```

Instead you can override the module types entirely, which will in turn allow you to override the interface

In a `globals.d.ts` (or any .d.ts file)

```
import * as Express from "express";

declare module "Express" {
  interface Request {
    signedCookies?: unknown
  }
}
```

Then this works:

```js
export function getLogin(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const signedCookies = req.signedCookies;
  //   ^? type = unknown
}
```

Read more about module overriding at this question: [How to override or extend a libary type definition in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952198/17954209)