# How to make a generic type from a js class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using [Fuse.js](https://www.fusejs.io/) and it's written in JS. To use it simply create an instance:

```js
const fuse = new Fuse(data)
```

The type of `fuse` is just `Fuse`. I want it to automatically be more specified by making the type `Fuse` a generic. How can I do that?

Currently I have to manually type them like this:

```js
const fuseData1: FuseData1 = new Fuse(data1)
const fuseData2: FuseData2 = new Fuse(data2)
```

Comment: You can try to 'override' types provided by fuse.js with your own where `Fuse` is generic (by changing its signature and its constructor). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952198/how-to-override-or-extend-a-libary-type-definition-in-typescript

Comment: I'm don't know how the answer in that question be relevant to me. Overriding the type this seems that I can't inherit other properties that `Fuse` already provide me. Is that correct?

Comment: You can augment definitions instead of overwriting them. But I just checked with fuse.js in particular, and `Fuse` seem to be generic class already. Could you check if you're using latest version of fuse.js?

Comment: I guess this question depends strongly on whatever fuse.js is. If you don't get proper engagement here you might want to [edit] to make it a [mre] without external dependencies, the answer to which would hopefully help with your use case.