# Local type definitions for an imported JS module not being recognized

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am importing an untyped JS NPM module using the `import * as ss from 'simple-ajax-uploader'` syntax. I have created a type definition file at `/scripts/@types/simple-ajax-uploader/index.d.ts`, which I would expect VS Code to recognize per the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/",
      "./scripts/@types/"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

I *do* get intellisense if I do one **or** other of the following:

1. Put the definition file in `node_modules/@types/simple-ajax-uploader`
2. Remove the `import` (thus treating `ss` as a global variable).

However, I can't get local type definitions to work with an import. My module compiles, but I don't get any intellisense when I type `ss.` - the variable is apparently being treated treated as `any`.

My (thus far minimal) definition file, for what it's worth:

```
export as namespace ss;

export interface SimpleUploadOptions {
    // TODO
}   

export class SimpleUpload {
    constructor (options: SimpleUploadOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `typeRoots` is only used for loading declarations for globally defined identifiers (hence why it worked when I removed the import statement). For imported modules you need to use the `paths` property in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths" :{
  "*": ["./scripts/@types/*", "*"]
}
```

This tells the compiler to look in the specified folder (in addition to the default locations, e.g. `node_modules`) when performing module resolution.

(Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326719/3248302 for pointing me in the right direction.)