# TypeScript - Cannot import self in types override in other types root, TS7016

Tags: node.js, typescript, feathersjs

I am working with FeathersJS and TypeScript.
As it is still under development (TS for Feathers) I found that I need to override types for that to be able to adjust to my case (e.g. pagination can be disabled or enabled and types should handle it but don't at the moment).

In my tsconfig.json I have the following:

```
"typeRoots": [                            /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
      "./types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

The order does not matter as I have tried with node_modules first too.

I put the folder `feathersjs__feathers` in `./types` with just `index.d.ts` (removed `package.json`) with exact copy of the types from DefinitelyTyped.

This line is causing the issue: `import * as self from '@feathersjs/feathers';`

> TS7016
>   could not find a declaration file for module '@feathersjs/feathers'. 'C:/Users/marek/dev/system/api — kopia/node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/feathersjs__feathers` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'feathersjs__feathers';`

I have tried to add the `package.json` to my folder, like that:

```
{
  "name": "@types/feathersjs__feathers",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "types": "index.d.ts"
}
```

but it does not help with that issue. 
If I install `@types/feathersjs__feathers` so it is there in `node_modules` there is no error, but no matter what order in `typeRoots` it takes types from that types, not from my override.

Any solutions for that?

Generally the config with `./types` and folders with `index.d.ts` is fine as e.g. for `feathers-mongoose` I have my own typings there and they are working properly. The issue is just with importing self...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`typeRoots` only helps the TypeScript compiler find files to load for the `types` option (or the `/// <reference types="..."/>` directive) for the benefit of any `declare module "..." { ... }` and global declarations they contain.  But the `index.d.ts` file for `@feathersjs/feathers` does not use `declare module "..." { ... }`; it is intended to be found as a module itself by TypeScript's main module resolution process.  That process doesn't honor `typeRoots` and is hard-wired to look in `node_modules/@types` when it finds an untyped module in `node_modules`.  To get module resolution to look an additional place, you have to use the `baseUrl` and `paths` options:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@feathersjs/feathers": ["types/feathersjs__feathers"]
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like poor design to me, but [the TypeScript team has already said once that the behavior is intentional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13581), so I don't think it's worth filing a bug to ask them to change it.

(I noticed that the Stack Overflow "Related" widget found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326719) that does basically answer your question, though IMO it's not as clear as my answer.)

Comment: This NEEDS to be documented. I was trying to load a typings package that I copied out of `node_modules` and expected to be able to include `my/custom/path` in `typeRoots` and have it resolve types exactly the same as it does with `node_modules`. PLEASE update this page! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html