# How to configure paths property in tsconfig.json file for external libraries

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

The closest explanation for what I am trying to do was found here [[a link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module).  Still I am struggling to get my solution to compile.

I have external typings which I would like to use in my project and all of them has *.d.ts files with namespace "DS/*" which I store in a folder called typings.  Below is my folder structure for my simple Angular app.

```js
-MyAppName
--typings
----all my modules d.ts
--src
----app
-tsconfig.json
```

this is my tsconfig.json file look like below

```js
"compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "DS/*": [
        "typings/*"
      ],
      "*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "typings/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
```

I get an error for importing my library as below
import { MyModuleName } from 'DS/MyModuleName';

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'DS/MyModuleName' in 'MyAppName\src\app'

I'm using AngularCLI to build the app.  I have failed to configure my tsconfig file to support these externally imported libraries.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

according to your tree, try in your tsconfig.ts

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "typings" ]...

"paths": {
  "DS/*": [
    "typings/*"
  ],
}

"include": ["src", "typings"],
```

then in your app.module.ts

```
import { MyModuleName} from 'DS/myModuleName.module';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply but I still get the same error

`ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../typings/MyModuleName' in 'MyAppName\src\app'`

Comment: Also I thought the whole purpose of setting 
`"paths": {
      "DS/*": [
        "typings/*"
      ],`
is so I can refer to the imports as "DS/..."?

Comment: mocked it up in my application here and discovered a combo that works. see edited answer above and let me know. cheers

Comment: I don't get any errors in my Visual Code editor for these libraries.  The auto completion correctly recognizes the libraries but when I do a `ng build`  it still throws the error `ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'DS/MyModuleName/shared.module' in 'MyAppName\src\app'`