# Typescript Custom Type for JS lib, import not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, typescript2.0

I have a vue project with typescript and I an importing a custom type that I create for the [vue-numeral-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-numeral-filter), but this generates the error:

> ERROR in /Users/bmartins/Development/app-invest/src/main.ts(14,30):
> 14:30 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-numeral-filter'. '/Users/bmartins/Development/app-invest/node_modules/vue-numeral-filter/dist/vue-numeral-filter.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm install @types/vue-numeral-filter` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-numeral-filter';`

On my main.ts file I have:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import router from './router';
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import store from './store';
import { mockStore } from './test/mock/store';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pt-br';
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment';
import { API_URL, PRODUCT_TYPES } from './store/constants';
import VueNumeralFilter from 'vue-numeral-filter';

Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts);

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueNumeralFilter, { locale: 'pt-br' });
Vue.use(VueMoment, {
  moment,
});
```

For the type I create the folder structure:

```
App 
|_ src 
|_ types    
   |_ vue-numeral-filter
        |_ index.d.ts
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvvXA.png)

The index.d.ts I created based on the [@types/vue-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vue-moment):

```js
import Numeral from 'numeral';
import { PluginObject } from 'vue';

declare namespace VueNumeralFilterPlugin {
  interface Options {
    // The optional (self-maintained) numeral instance
    numeral?: Numeral;
  }
  interface VueStatic extends Numeral {
    (inp?: Numeral, format?: string): string;
    (inp?: Numeral): string;
  }
}

declare module 'vue-numeral-filter' {
  interface Vue {
    $numeral: VueNumeralFilterPlugin.VueStatic;
  }
}

type VueNumeralFilter = PluginObject<undefined>;

declare const VueNumeralFilter: VueNumeralFilter;
export = VueNumeralFilter;
```

And the last part was changing the tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "vue-numeral-filter",
      "vuetify-form-base"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I read this post [TypeScript 2: custom typings for untyped npm module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module), several times which has an amazing explanation but still didn't figure out how to fix it...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type definition files can be a little finicky in Typescript. It's very easy to end up writing something that TypeScript interprets as a module instead of a declaration file. When this happens, TypeScript starts expecting you to import types from the file directly, instead of recognising the embedded type declaration.

It looks to me like your type definition file is incorrect. In particular, you've got `import`s outside the module declaration, which is one of the flags that TypeScript recognises as a module marker. If you move your `import`s so that they are inside the `declare { ... }` block, I think it will start working.

On a different note, I think the `typeRoots` and `types` entries in your `tsconfig.json` file are overly restrictive. I don't think that's what's causing the problem here, but I think you should remove them otherwise you will have trouble installing 3rd-party types in future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works!
I also notice if I take the exact declaration file and move to the node_module in the @types folder it works! Seems the declaration files inside node_modules has some diff interpretation as well!