# Typescript : Property select doesn't exist on typeof control

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I am trying to use a custom control [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-select) for leaflet. I am writing an angular app, hence using typescript.

Typescript is throws an error " Property  doesn't exist on typeof contorl" every time I try to use any library for custom leaflet contorl. How can I silence this warning?

```
var select = L.control.select({
      label: 'Select',
      data: [{ title: String }],
      selected: function (item) {
        //callback when item is selected  
      },
      opened: function () {
        //callback when dropdown opens
      },
      closed: function () {
        //callback when dropdown closes
      }
    });

    select.addTo(map);
```

[image]

Comment: did you install the typings for that library?

Comment: I don’t think the author published typings since looks like library was meant to be used with Javascript. I am open to explore and write typings myself. Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: Here is a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25138584/1778465